# Masstransit saga fault handling

Tags: .net, .net-core, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to create a simple saga error handling scenario using masstransit and azure sb and have got the following working for the receiver.

The saga currently throws an error in one of the steps and after a few retries is sent to the _error queue as expected.

Depending on the step that causes the error in the saga, the message will be handled by *Step1FaultConsumer* or *Step2FaultConsumer*. I wanted to know if there is a better way to handle the errors from the entire saga from a single location regardless of the step that causes the error.

I'm trying to do this without using a state machine if possible.

program.cs

```
 var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
        {
            var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("HostAddress"),
                h =>
                {
                    h.TransportType = TransportType.AmqpWebSockets;
                    h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                    h.RetryLimit = 5;
                    h.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey", "SharedAccessKey");
                });

            cfg.RequiresSession = true;
            cfg.UseRetry(x => x.Exponential(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "QueueName", e =>
            {
                e.RequiresSession = true;
                e.Saga<SagaConsumer>(new MessageSessionSagaRepository<SagaConsumer>());
                e.Consumer<Step1FaultConsumer>();
                e.Consumer<Step2FaultConsumer>();
            });
        });
```

saga.cs

```
public class SagaConsumer:
    ISaga,
    InitiatedBy<ISagaStep1>,
    Orchestrates<ISagaStep2>
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ISagaStep1> context)
    {
        if(context.Message.Input1 == "000")
             throw new Exception("Saga Step 1 Exception");
        await context.Send<ISagaStep2>(context.DestinationAddress, new { Input2 = $"2-{context.Message.Input1}" });
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ISagaStep2> context)
    {
        throw new Exception("Saga Step 2 Exception");
    }
}

public class Step1FaultConsumer:
    IConsumer<Fault<ISagaStep1>>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<ISagaStep1>> context)
    {
        // Handle Error
    }
}

public class Step2FaultConsumer:
    IConsumer<Fault<ISagaStep2>>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<ISagaStep2>> context)
    {
        // Handle Error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your consumer to handle both fault types, via two `IConsumer<T>` interfaces, and two Consume methods.

I would also suggest using a separate queue/receive-endpoint for the error consumer(s), to avoid clogging up throughput on your saga endpoint.